# Chern character of the restriction of a canonical bundle over product space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I am new to StackExchange, and self-taught in the field of characteristic classes, vector bundles, etc... so apologies in advance if my question is somewhat trivial or ill-posed.

I am trying to do a concrete computation using general facts I've gathered from notes and books on the web. The setup is as follows. Let $M$ be the complex manifold $M = \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{CP}^1$ and the $N \subset M$ the submanifold $N = \mathbb{CP}^1$ . I would like to compute the Chern character of $K_M|N$, the canonical bundle over $M$ restricted to $N$.

From what I gathered, it seems the adjunction formula could be helpful (see e.g. Corollary 2.25 [here](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/%7Ejoelfine/preprints/Kahler_intro_ch2.pdf)),
\begin{equation}
K_N = K_M|N \otimes L_N^{-1}|N \, .
\end{equation}
This should somehow allow me to express $ch(K_M|N)$ in terms of $ch(K_N) = 1 + c_1(K_N) = 1 - c_1(\mathbb{CP}^1)$, using that $ch(E\otimes F) = ch(E) ch(F)$.

The question is about the meaning and contribution of the second factor in the adjunction formula. Can someone give me a clearer idea of what this inverse line bundle over $N$ is, what does it mean for it to be itself restricted to $N$, and how to compute its Chern character in terms of characteristic classes of $N$ for the case $N = \mathbb{CP}^1$?

I feel that, due to the triviality of $M$ and $N$ above, the answer should be somewhat simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In general $L_N^{-1}$ restricted to $N$ is the normal bundle of $N$ inside $M$. Its contribution to the adjunction formula depends very much on how $N$ is embedded in $M$. However, in your case, $N$ is the fibre of a projection $M \rightarrow \mathbf C$, so its normal bundle is trivial, and hence $K_M$ restricted to $N$ equals $K_N$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer (and the sanity check).